# Scaling Rails Needs A Lot Of Nginx Instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, scaling

We have built a rails app and are trying to support around 6k concurrent users making on average 6 request each per minute, with an average rails web transaction response time of 700 ms.

We did the maths, and it works out that we would need around 420 nginx/passenger instances running (we are not running in multithreaded mode due to legacy codebase that may not be threadsafe). This seems like an awful lot of nginx instances needed to support this kind of load.
We are running 20 nginx/passenger instances per server at the moment, so we need about 20 servers to get to the 420 instances of nginx/passenger required to serve that traffic.

Here is the math:

```
6k Users X 6 RPM Per User = 36k Total RPM
36k X .7 Seconds (AVG response time) = 25200 seconds of processing
25200/60 = 420 instances (Divide by 60 to fit all that processing into 1 min)
```

Does anybody have any experience around this that could help us out?
Is this just how it has to be with the amount of servers we must run?

thanks

Comment: This might be a better question on serverfault.com

Comment: Response time from the DB doesn't count for processing time. This are some made up calculations, you need to load test with something like siege or website/service agains real instance and then calculate.
Also passenger (if that is what you are going to use) can run multiple processes.

Comment: I should clarify that we are using 20 passenger instances per server at the moment. Also, when I said response time, I actually meant the entire response time from the web server, encompassing all db queries and actual processing time. I have amended my question with these details.

Comment: To minimize the processing time have you used caching of some kind in your application like memcache/redis or http caching for static files? I will also suggest for you to use tools like seige first. Btw your server has how many cores/ram? is this application based for emails by any chance?